# why the destructor is called only one time when the constructor is called 5 times?

Tags: c++, constructor, dynamic-memory-allocation, destructor, new-operator

I'm trying to learn more about C++ ,int this code I'm allocating an array of A's  (5 in this case), what I understand that 5 A's will be allocated ...so the compiler will call 5 times the constructer , but in case of deleting that array it calls the destructor one time only ,so my question is why does it call the destructor one time only when it has 5 A's , shouldn't he call the destructor 5 times??

I have this code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A() { std::cout << "IM in C'tor" << std::endl; };
    ~A() { std::cout << "IM in De'tor" << std::endl; }
};


int main()

{
    A* a = new A[5];
    delete a;  // ingone the errors,the important thing is calling the 
                 C'tor and D'tor` 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new[]` and `delete[]` should be used in pair. So `delete[] a;`.

Comment: Your `cout` statements in the destructor and constructor should print `this`, not just a simple message.  If you did that, you will see what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `delete[] a` to delete an array of things allocated with `new[]`. If you do that, you'll see the correct output:

```
IM in C'tor
IM in C'tor
IM in C'tor
IM in C'tor
IM in C'tor
IM in De'tor
IM in De'tor
IM in De'tor
IM in De'tor
IM in De'tor
```

Comment: Could've just closed this as dupe. Moreover this was a typo.

Comment: @Anoop, I don't consider this a typographical error, this is more a misunderstanding of the language features.

Comment: I see. I found the dupe.

Comment: ok.  lets say I didn't change my code , what does "delete a" deletes exactly, does is delete the first element in the array ? ?

Comment: @paxdiablo , I didn't write the code , it was a question in my exam

Comment: @sallyaaa It's UB (undefined behaviour), so all bets are off.  I'm surprised it didn't crash outright, actually.

Comment: yeah it didn't crash ,it throws an exception .